Is there a conflict of tenses here
It is the best book he ever wrote.
I think this sentence is not correct as " is" is present and "wrote " past. So there should be a conflict of tenses.
Am I right?
Would it be the same for
It was the best book he has ever written.
I dont think so because "has written" is also at the same time past and present .So there should not be a conflict of tenses.
Am I right too here?

There is no conflict of tenses here, and no requirement to make the tenses "correct". Your first question should always be: Does this tense say what I want to communicate? That's all.
Suppose our author wrote three books. We'll make them travel books:

Touring France (published in 2010)
Touring Italy (published in 2015)
Touring Greece (published in 2020)

Now we'll pick one, and make it "the best":

Touring Italy is the best book he ever wrote.

This sentence is correct. Wrote is correct, because you are describing a writing event that happened back in 2015. But it's also correct to say "is the best" (not was) because you are giving your opinion today about which book is best.
But you can also say:

Touring Italy was the best book he ever wrote.

This could mean various things depending on context. One simple meaning is that you want to emphasise the past moment and quality of writing, so you put everything in the past tense. It was his best book, and he hasn't written anything comparable since.
In all of this the important point is, different tenses can all be correct if they communicate the message you want to send.
